# Quantiles from Lognormal distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, monte-carlo

Is there a closed form solution for the quantiles of the lognormal distribution. And if so can they also be interpreted as Value at Risk measures? F.e. is the 5% quantile of a lognormal PDF equivalent to the 5% VaR?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a normal r.v. and $Y = e^X$. The quantiles of $Y$ are simply obtained by exponentiating the quantiles of $X$.

Now there's no [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) expression for the quantiles of the *normal* distribution; consequently, there's no closed form expression for the quantiles of a lognormal.

However, as indicated in my opening paragraph, you can express the quantiles of a lognormal in terms of the quantiles of the corresponding normal. If $x_q = \mu+\Phi^{-1}(q)\cdot \sigma$ is the $q$-quantile of a normal with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then $y_q = e^{x_q}$ is the corresponding quantile of the [lognormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with the same parameters.

Since functions are typically available which give normal quantiles to quite high accuracy, you can make use of those in calculations involving lognormal quantiles.

A value at risk (VaR) is a quantile, so these considerations apply to value at risk.

Comment: so lets say if I have Log(S) is normally distributed with mean 8.91 and standard deviation 1.95 (where S is a stock). If I use the formula u stated it would be possible to determine the VaR as a quantile i.e. for 95% it would be with (S_0 =50) 50*exp(8.91-1.645*1.95) right? I also use the one sided z measure as VaR is only one sided.

Comment: Yes, VaR is one-sided (investment VaRs are lower tail quantiles, insurance VaRs are upper tail quantiles). I'm not clear on what $S_0$ is in your question but the remainder of the calculation looks right. However, beware -- if your mean and standard deviation are not population quantities but are instead estimated from a sample, this changes things.

Comment: are these also additive? since for the normal case there is a formula.

Comment: what do you mean by additive here? What's additive with what?

Comment: say if I have two stocks with a VaR can I also somehow extract the  VaR of a portfolio lets say if I have 1 unit of 1 stock and 0.5 units of the other. Is it possible to weight the VaRs  to get the VaR of the portfolio?

Comment: Ah, I see; the sum components of a multivariate normal are also normal; this is not true of lognormals (though a lognormal with the same population mean and variance as the sum is often a reasonable approximation, it's often not so great in the far tail), A number of posts on the site discuss sums of lognormals (though they mostly focus on the independent case). One can of course readily simulate and get good accuracy, or if there's only a few stocks in the portfolio numerical integration is possible. If they were independent (which is not normally the case, numerical convolution would work)..

Comment: ... There's also comonotonicity bounds.